# Vopono setup with Proton VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn

Pretty new with Linux and have been trying to use Vopono to split tunnel my VPN connections with Proton VPN as my provider

Currently I am going through the steps to setup the configuration files and when I get to the section asking for this:

***"Please log-in at https://account.protonvpn.com/dashboard and then visit https://account.protonvpn.com/api/vpn/v2/users and copy the value of the cookie starting with "AUTH-" in the request from your browser's network request inspector:"***

I enter said AUTH string and get the response:

***"Error: invalid Zip archive: Could not find central directory end"***

Anyone able to help me figure this out?

EDIT: Ubuntu 22.04.2

Comment: This sounds like a question that could be answered by ProtonVPN. Have you asked them?

Comment: ProtonVPN wouldn't help, this product is 3rd party and not something they work with unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks for the help!

I managed to speak with the people who created vopono and it looks like a problem with a change made by ProtonVPN (Nothing Ubuntu related!)

:)